# Setting the date to a variable in SQL to call in export file naming convention

Tags: sql, sql-server, var

I have a working exporting script, however I want to improve it by adding todays date to the naming convention of the output. I have tried declaring getdate() to a variable and then calling it but I cannot get it to work.
I currently have:

```
@export on;
@export set filename="\path\to\file\currentdate.txt";
@export off;
```

I tried:

```
DECLARE @currentdate date = getdate()
```

Then in my export using @currentdate. But the file ended up being named @currentdate.txt.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using DBvisualiser 10

Comment: Yes, but you connect DbVis to some dbms server - which one?

Comment: oh sorry, MS sql server

Answer (score 0):

seems like you can use DBVisulizaer Pre-defined Variables:

```
@export set filename="\path\to\file\${dbvis-date}$.txt";
```

or

```
@export set filename="\path\to\file\${myDate||now||Date}$.txt";
```

[Using DbVisualizer Variables](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG110/Using+DbVisualizer+Variables)

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, that doesn't work either and prints $dbvis-date$.txt still

Comment: @starbucks how about now

Comment: Now Im getting an error: parameter "+${dbvis-date}$+" is not valid for command

Comment: @Starbucks - I'm not sure then m this is how it shows in the documentations

Comment: no worries, thanks anyway. Will come back if I solve it